# Kuzzle create index with mapping when importing CSV date fields

Tags: node.js, csv, import, kuzzle

I have a CSV file with:

```
fname,lname,age,phone,address,dob
chris,jack,51,656-724-7821,aaaaa,03/01/2016 12:00:01 AM
joe,freds,44,545-724-7821,fsdfds sdfsdfsf sdfsdf,03/01/2015 12:00:01 AM
```

and a mapping defined as:

```
const new1Mappings = {
        properties: {
            fname: {
                "type": "text"
            },
            lname: {
                "type": "text"
            },
            age: {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            phone: {
                "type": "text"
            },
            address: {
                "type": "text"
            },
            dob: {
                "type": "text" <----- issue is here
            }
        }
    };
```

Now using the Kuzzle API to import the CSV:

```
await kuzzle.collection.create('new1', 'contacts', new1Mappings);
await kuzzle.bulk.mWrite('new1', 'contacts', data); // data is an array built from the contents of the CSV file
```

When I set the mapping type for the "dob" field to "text" the collection document is created but is not searchable as a date field.
If I change the mapping type for "dob" to "date" then no documents are created in the collection.

What mapping data type should a CSV date field be specified as?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, to be able to search on the `dob` field as a date you'll need to set the type `date` in the mapping.

Concerning the creation of the documents, your data need to fit with the [Elasticsearch date type field data model](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#:%7E:text=JSON%20doesn%27t%20have%20a,%2Dsince%2Dthe%2Depoch.).

However, you might be able to adapt the mapping model using [Elasticsearch Multi date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#multiple-date-formats).

Answer (score 0):

I was passing in an incorrect date time string format.

```
chris,jack,51,656-724-7821,aaaaa,03/01/2016 12:00:01 AM
```

for

```
dob: {
         "type": "text" <----- issue is here
     }
```

So I changed the CSV to

```
chris,jackson,51,444-555-555,aaaaa,2021-01-01 01:00:00
```

and the mapping to

```
dob: {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
     }
```

All good now.